# issue to get pagination in tumblr library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tumblr

i have problem in Tumblr library in Codeigniter i have use this code

```
 $countpages=count($posts); //count my all posts  
 $allpages = $this->tumblr->read_pages($countpages);
```

i have got error in this  line in library

```
$params = array();
array_push($params, "email=".$this->tumblr_email, "password=".$this->tumblr_password);
$xml = $this->make_request($this->tumblr_blog_url.'/api/pages', implode("&", $params), $method);
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: this error"Type: Exception
Message: Problem with http://fashion.tumblr.com/api/pages,"